# Rational numbers don't have lub property

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

A counterexample is $A=\{x\in\mathbb Q | x>0 \land x^2<2\}$ but for this set, how come $\sqrt 2$ is not the supremum of the set? I don't understand it.

Even if I see some explanations, I think $\sqrt 2$ is the sup. Can you help me for figuring out this?

Comment: It's just not in Q.

Comment: Sup does not need to be in the set already? (0,1) has sup=1 but 1 is not in the set.

Comment: A supremum is defined relative to a subset within a partially ordered set. So in your original post, the partially ordered set is Q, and the subset is x^2 < 2. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum